# Case When Statement - Three columns

Tags: t-sql, case-when

**Advanced case when statement in T-SQL using three columns**

Hope someone can help with the following :)

I have two tables in SQL.

- Table 1 has 4 columns - person_id, A, B, and C.
- Table 2 has 3 look-up columns - A, B, and C

I want to carry out the following:

- Look down Table 1, column A, find value in Table 2, column A
- If no value, go to Table 1, column B.
- Look down Table 1, column B, find value in Table 2, column B
- If no value, go to Table 1, column C
- Look down Table 1, column C, find value in Table 2, column C
- If no values in any column put 'Null'

So I know how to write a simple case when statement. However, I think that 'case when' only works on one column. I've started to write out the code but need help to get it right.

```
Select person_id, 
case when 1.A is not null then 2.A
when 1.B is not null then 2.B
else 1.C
end as CODE
from table 1
left join table 2
Order by person_id
```

Would appreciate any help you can give, thank you.

Comment: Please remove your descriptions and instead include actual sample input and output data.  If the ordering would not be obvious from that alone, then you may add some more explanation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. I can't add the data I'm working with as its restricted. What would you suggest please?

Comment: your else is 1.c so if no other matches happen, it will return that. your else needs to be NULL.

Comment: @Louis-York: Make some data up. Doesn't need to be the real thing just convey the situation.

Comment: Sorry for not posting tables, just trying to work out how to create a table in markdown as it won't let me paste a table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql seems mostly correct, except for the `else 1.C`.

Since a `CASE WHEN` will return 1 value, depending on the first positive `WHEN` criteria.

And a `CASE` returns NULL as default.
So `ELSE null` isn't really needed.

The table descriptions do indicate that Table2 only contains 1 row.

If so, then you can cross join them.

```
SELECT t1.person_id, 
CASE 
WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t2.A
WHEN t1.B IS NOT NULL THEN t2.B
WHEN t1.C IS NOT NULL THEN t2.C
END AS [CODE]
FROM [Table 1] t1
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT TOP 1 A, B, C
   FROM [Table 2]
   ORDER BY A DESC, B DESC, C DESC
) t2
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just used this code up to and including 'from'. The else part was wrong. I've put a 'when' line in with a condition. I've also added a condition of 'and does not contain' to all three of the 'whens' so it's now working perfectly. Thank you so much!